# When is the category of representations compact?

Tags: category-theory, representation-theory

I already know that given a compact Lie group $G$ it's category of (continuous unitary) representations Rep$(G)$ is compact, i.e. allows duals. However I can't seem to find a good reference about the case of non-compact groups or infinite-dimensional representations.

For example on how to construct the unit morphism.

Are there good references for this topic?

PS: As a physicist I was especially looking for the case of the Poincaré group.

Comment: The category of finite-dimensional representations of any topological group $G$ admits duals; the dual of $V$ is $V^{\ast} = \text{Hom}(V, \mathbb{C})$ as usual. Do you also want to consider infinite-dimensional representations?

Comment: Yes, i indeed forgot to mention this in my question.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Do you know of any theorems or references on the generalization to infinite-dimensional reps?